# insserv: Service localfs has to be enabled to start service vmware-USBArbitrator

Tags: 16.04, startup, systemd, vmware-player

I have installed [VMWare Player](http://www.vmware.com/products/player/playerpro-evaluation.html) on my Ubuntu 16.04 system, which works fine.

Lately I have been looking into how I can trim down the excess services running on my system, and I came across `vmware` and `vmware-USBArbitrator` (both of which I use quite infrequently, and can be fired up on demand).

When I try `sudo systemctl is-enabled vmware-USBArbitrator.service` I see

```
vmware-USBArbitrator.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install is-enabled vmware-USBArbitrator
enabled
```

When I try to disable the same, using `sudo systemctl disable vmware-USBArbitrator.service`, I get

```
vmware-USBArbitrator.service is not a native service, redirecting to systemd-sysv-install
Executing /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install disable vmware-USBArbitrator
insserv: Service localfs has to be enabled to start service vmware-USBArbitrator
insserv: exiting now!
update-rc.d: error: insserv rejected the script header
```

`/etc/init.d/vmware-USBArbitrator` indeed mentions a `localfs` service:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#
# Copyright 1998-2010 VMware, Inc.  All rights reserved.
#
# This script manages the VMware USB Arbitrator service
#

### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides: vmware-USBArbitrator
# Required-Start: localfs
# Required-Stop: localfs
# X-Start-Before: 
# X-Stop-After: 
# Default-Start: 2 3 4
# Default-Stop: 0 6
# Short-Description: This services starts and stops the USB Arbitrator.
### END INIT INFO

### ... the script continues ...
```

I looked around quite a bit for a `localfs`, `local-fs` or `local_fs` service (my `/etc/` directory, various service-management commands like `status`, `systemctl` and `rcconf`, as well as dear old Google), but nothing useful came up (except for [this LaunchPad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1426588) which mentions the exact error, but the bug itself is related to `systemd` and no solution is given for  the `vmware-USBArbitrator.service` configuration issue).

Any ideas on how I can get this issue resolved, and disable `vmware-USBArbitrator.service` from automatically starting up at boot?

Answer (score 2):

Replace `localfs` with `$local_fs` like:

```
# Required-Start: $localfs
# Required-Stop: $localfs
```

or `touch` a dummy init script called `localfs` to work around this

Comment: Thanks - I no longer use VMWare so I'll accept this if someone else happens to confirm that this is working.